# TFS - Git Endpoint Connection Update

Tags: git, tfs, connection, endpoint

So upon changing a repo location, we needed to adjust he server URL in the git endpoint connection to TFS. When attempting to save the connection update prompt, it requires a password. Is this something new? We did not need any credentials before to update connections.

Comment: What's the version of TFS do you use? Do you mean that it prompts to enter the password when you update the external Git endpoint? Could you please share the repro steps or capture the screenshot for the issue you mentioned?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT So basically yes when updating the external git endpoint. The connection between TFS and Git pretty much. When creating it, we don't need to enter a user or pass, but when updating, it requires default password now. We use TFS 2018.

Answer (score 0):

It could require a password because of the git credential helper use (type `git config credential.helper`)

If you did not have to enter a password before, it might be because that credential (usually the Windows Credential Manager on Windows) had cached said credentials for the old URL.

Comment: So this is all serverwide, not local at all. We use TFS 2018 and Github Enterprise within our servers, and the password defaults to one we have as a secret for the admin account. Basically we need it so it does not default at all.

Comment: @RahiedLaskar Still, on the server side, it is still valid to check the `credential.helper`, to make sure it does not interfere.